# How to request server when Internet is coming

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, pinia

I have such a script, there are internet connection listeners and when it

changes I want the whole page to reload. Because when I mount

components, a request is made to the server.

i use pinia so I can't just reload the page

this is how i do it now

App.vue file

```
<template>
  <Header />
  <div class="app">
      <router-view v-if="!isLoading"></router-view>
      <div v-else class="loader-container">
          <Loader />
      </div>
      <NoConnection v-if="!onLine" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    computed: {
      ...mapWritableState(useUserStore, ["username", "token"]),
    },
    data() {
        return {
            isLoading: true,
            onLine: navigator.onLine,
            key: 0
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async checkAuth(tokenAuth) {
            try {
                const response = await axios.post('/api/users',{}, {
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": tokenAuth,
                    }
                })
                this.token = tokenAuth
                this.username = response.data.display_name
            } catch (e) {
                if(e.response.status === 401) {
                    this.$router.push('/auth/')
                }
            } finally {
                this.isLoading = false
            }
        },
        updateOnlineStatus(e) {
            const { type } = e
            this.onLine = type === 'online'
            if(this.token) {
              this.key += 1
            } else {
                this.checkAuth()
                this.key += 1
            }
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        window.addEventListener('online', this.updateOnlineStatus)
        window.addEventListener('offline', this.updateOnlineStatus)
        const tokenAuth = localStorage.getItem("token")
        this.checkAuth(tokenAuth)
    },
  }
</script>
```

Here, when the Internet appears, I change the component key so that it
reboots, but it seems to me that this is some kind of crutch and I'm
doing something wrong

Am I doing everything right?

I did not find anything on this topic, only how to check the Internet connection

found only how to update and re-render a component

Comment: What do you mean "Internet appears?"

Comment: @OldProgrammer onLine = true

Comment: It's unclear why is there a necessity for key and why pinia makes it special. Reloading data on online isn't different than reloading for any other reason. If there's reactive data to update in a view, it will be updated when a store is updated